# Amazon Lambda with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a database (`MySQL`) created in Amazon RDS. Also created a PHP class for connecting to that database and which will return some webservice as `JSON` format according to the request. Which I am using for my mobile and Angular applications.

Currently I am hosting that php file in one of my GoDaddy server and calling that PHP file from the app(s).

My question is - can I use AWS Lambda for this purpose (for deploying php file ) ? In some tutorials I found Lambda will not support PHP.

The PHP file serves the following functionalities

1. Creating various JSON files from MySQL table.
2. Uploading images to Amazon S3 bucket.
3. Sending push notifications (FCM) to Android / iOS devices.

Comment: What do you mean by "for deploying php file"? Like, copy a php file to some servier using lambda?

Comment: AWS lambda currently does not support PHP, reference: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

Comment: @NiminUnnikrishnan - so if I convert from PHP to Node.JS, Lambda can serve my requirement?

Comment: yes, you will be able to

Comment: You can Use [Bref](https://bref.sh/) as an AWS Lambda layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Lambda currently does not support PHP.
You could use any one of the supported languages for your purpose.

For push notifications you could use SNS

Read more: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

Comment: You can Use [Bref](https://bref.sh/) as an AWS Lambda layer